# Ajax add record with session id and user id issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an add friend system and i want to make an ajax call but it is not working, i want ajax to insert in the table the session id (me) and friend id,but i have no luck, i am a begginer.

JS CODE:

```
    $('#add').click(function(){
  var u =  "<?php echo $_SESSION["user"];?>";
  var f =  "<?php echo $_GET["u"];?>"; 
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",

      url: "?u="+u+"&add="+f,
      success: function(){
         alert("success");
      }
   });
});


 <a id='add' class='btn btn-success' href=\"#\">Add as friend</a>
```

Any help apreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are sending a "post" request this will be never handled you had to send it with a "GET" method see this it may help

```
('#add').click(function(){
   var u = `"<?php echo $u->id?>"` <--- this is friend id
 var id = "<?php echo  $_SESSION['user']";?> <---- this is my id


     $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url : "?u="+u+"&add="+id,
          success: function(data){//here the function should have a parameter which is the response of your request
             alert(data);//try to debug it and see what is the response or alert("success")
          }
```

in you php file you can get those parameters simply by using 
`$_GET["u"]` and `$_GET["add"]` to use them in your request for inserting

Comment: Thanks for reply, nothing is happening when i press "add button", for the request to be an success it must be like this in the address: profile.php?u=1&add=2 - for example,

Comment: so this is a GET request not a "post" as you havd mentioned !! try to change method from "post" to "get" in your code and it will work

Comment: Is working now, thanks guys, i have updated the js code.

Comment: Is working with GET, see the updated code on top, one question, if i want on success to change my "add friend " button to " request sent " after i send the request, how can i do that?

Comment: you simply can add this after the success $("#add").text("Friend Request Sent") by the way the method is still post on your

Comment: Yes is method POST , i'm tired :) , i have GET on the var f, sorry.

Comment: Hmm, on  $("#add").text("Friend Request Sent") as u mentioned, if i refresh the page, the button is back with the add friend..

Comment: think about adding another 'field' in your Database which remain to the situation of the friendship between users for example 0 -> not friends , 1-> friends , 2 -> still waiting the other to accept and on this parameter you will display that value on the button with a simple test , sure after getting it

Comment: and to be more optimal think about adding a new table on your DB call it invits in which you will save those 4 fields (id - id of receiver - id of sender , status)

Comment: i have a table friend requests with id,sender,recipient and status, but now i can't figure'it out how to implement the status process..with request sent and stuff..

Comment: it's all simple first when user A invits user B you will set a row in your DB having as id an auto_generated id and the user id from session and the receiver id from a hidden input or anything you want and for the statut you will set by default 2 for example , so since is it 2 on DB the receiver will have a notification telling him to accept or decline the sender invit so if it was accepted you made an update to that row by setting it to 1 , or let it 2 if he decline it you can implement it with the same code you're typing ahead

Comment: Okay bro i will try this

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes arround php tag

```
  var u = "<?php echo $u->id;?>";
  var id = "<?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?>";
```

Also  change here remove extra single quotes.

```
url: "?u="+u+"&add="+id,
```